# Is it possible make dump of mysql database with updated content in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am going to write scripts to make backup of mysql database using codeigniter.
However, here is one tricky issue.
I should convert all email into dummy letters not real email information.
Ex, Jon@gmail.com => aBdsEDd@test.com

So, the new dev can use all data, but not real email because of they are for real person's information.
But I am not sure It is possible or not.

Here, I dropped my approach, but can not change current database.

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$this->load->helper('file');
$this->load->helper('download');

$dumpOption = array(
    'tables'        => array(),   // Array of tables to backup.
    'ignore'        => array(),                     // List of tables to omit from the backup
    'format'        => 'txt',                       // gzip, zip, txt
    'filename'      => 'mybackup.sql',              // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
    'add_drop'      => TRUE,                        // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
    'add_insert'    => TRUE,                        // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
    'newline'       => "\n"                         // Newline character used in backup file
);

if(ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') {
    if ($this->dbutil->database_exists('db'))
    {
        $backup = $this->dbutil->backup($dumpOption);
        try {
            echo 'loading database .....';
            write_file('./mybackup.sql', $backup, 'w+');
            echo 'finish preparing dev data.';
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            printf('Message: ' .$e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        echo 'database does not exist.';
    }
}
```

Would you let me know If it is possible?
Most important thing is that the dump file should have updated content but we should not change original database, changes should be on dump only.

Is it possible?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, then answer is no, you cannot change the contents of the data this way, since the backup method takes a list of tables and dumps those to a file as they are. Well, this is exactly what you would expect from a backup solution.

What you could do, however, is to create views that incorporate the replacement logic you require. Then you can use the backup method to back the views up, not the tables.

Otherwise, you need to write the logic either in plain queries or implement it in php code and create the dump files yourself.

Comment: Or, could I add some queries in dump file? @Shadow

Comment: Not sure what queries you would like to add to the dump file.

Comment: when import dump sql file, update them dynamically. possible?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but by that time the developer can access the emails.

Comment: You are right. Then would you elaborate more to create views please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you have subsequent questions, pls ask a new question here on SO, don't do that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to change the data in-flight like this is going to be some blend of "inadvisable" and "impossible". What I do is first clone the DB to a staging location, and then run data scrub scripts for PII and other sensitive information. Then you can make *that* available to clone to dev environments.

However, for values like the email address that may be used in relations or otherwise be required to be unique you will want to take extra care, as we found out the hard way, when you change all the emails to `example@example.com` properly testing anything relating to that information becomes virtually impossible.

For something like this I would suggest deriving a dummy email from the real one, eg:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET email = CONCAT(
  SUBSTRING(MD5(email),1,16),
  '@',
  SUBSTRING(MD5(email),17,16),
  '.com'
);
```

Result:

```
foo@bar.com -> f3ada405ce890b6f@8204094deb12d8a8.com
bar@foo.com -> dc8a42aba3651b0b@1f088ef928ff3b1d.com
```

However, as your DB grows cloning like this becomes more and more of a problem, particularly for local development, as the DB size will likely only grow over time. As it stands our prod DB is approaching 300GB and some of our devs' machines cannot fit a copy in addition to all of their other requirements. Plus the cloning and scrubbing takes *hours*, and now with everyone remote it poses additional logistical problems to get those clones out to devs over already-constrained links.

The *best* solution, particularly for local dev, is to only dump the *schema* of the database and fill it with a representative set of mocked data for testing. For full-blown tests we maintain full-copy, scrubbed versions of the DB in our CI/CD pipeline environments.